# Help with Notepad++ Regex String Replacement

Tags: regex, notepad++

I'm not familiar with the regex string,

Let say i have this line of data in a file.:

```
define('DB_USER', 'audrey');
define('DB_USER', 'bobby');
define('DB_USER', 'cindy');
define('DB_USER', 'donny');
...
```

and i need to replace it into this:

```
define('DB_USER', 'admin');
define('DB_USER', 'admin');
define('DB_USER', 'admin');
define('DB_USER', 'admin');
...
```

Basically changing all the DB_user to admin. How can i do this with Notepad++ Find&Replace function. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Search for

```
define\('DB_USER',\s*'[^']*'\);
```

and replace with

```
define('DB_USER', 'admin');
```

Answer (score 0):

If the text is formatted as above, I'd use "block select"

Place cursor on `'` in `'audrey` and hold down left-alt-key and select the column, then just type in the replacement-wrord.

Comment: The text is actually spread across multiple documents. So i think regex will be a better fit. Thanks for the "Block select" tips, though :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

Search what: `,\s'\K\w+`
Replace with: `admin`